# Bootstrap 3.3.4 Glyphicons not working?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jsf, glyphicons

I have been trying a lot lately to get Glyphicons to work but with no luck. I'm using JSF framework with the following file structure.

[image]

Also I modified the CSS in bootstrap.css by removing (..) from every path in the following CSS code to become like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

  src: url('/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix')    format('embedded-opentype'), url('/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
   }
```

When not removing (..), JSF will show the following 2 warnings:

```
Warning:   JSF1091: No mime type could be found for file css/lib/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2.  To resolve this, add a mime-type mapping to the applications web.xml.
Warning:   JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, css/lib/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2.
```

But still always showing me a strange box instead of the Glyphicon that is supposed to show up?

Help please..

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by using the following expression to refer to the resources properly:

```
@font-face {

  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

  src: url("#{resource['default/1_0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot']}");
  src: url("#{resource['default/1_0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot']}") format('embedded-opentype'), url("#{resource['default/1_0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2']}") format('woff2'), url("#{resource['default/1_0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff']}") format('woff'), url("#{resource['default/1_0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf']}") format('truetype'), url("#{resource['default/1_0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg']}") format('svg');

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the fonts folder.

Replace your fonts folder with the one at: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap and it will work fine.